# AvalonDock: Multiple tool windows layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I'm using well-known docking library [AvalonDock 2.0](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) in my WPF project. The library supports MVVM and that's what I'm trying to do. A sample MVVM test application is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/chandramouleswaran/AvalonDock/tree/master/Version2.0/AvalonDock/AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp). I downloaded the sample and extended it to display the layout that I need, which roughly looks like this:

```
---------------------------
|                    |    |
|                    | T1 |
|                    |----|
|      Docs          |    |
|                    | T2 |
|                    |----|
|                    |    |
|                    | T3 |
---------------------------
```

As you can see, I have a main documents area and a tools area that has 3 `LayoutAnchorable`s that are docked to the right side and stacked vertically. Using MVVM, my window's ViewModel exposes a property named `Tools` that returns an array containing ViewModels of all my tool windows. I then bind this property to `AnchorablesSource` property of my docking control in XAML.

The problem however is that AvalonDock shows the 3 tool panes as 3 tabs instead of vertically stacking them.

Has anyone here used AvalonDock with MVVM? What is my way forward here? Does `LayoutInitializer` class have any role in solving this issue?

Comment: did you try using <LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Vertical" > and inside this all your LayoutAnchorable.

Comment: @N.J: Yes. I have done that and that does work. The problem however is that I need to do it the MVVM way, i.e. the orientation/layout should be dictated by a VM property, not be static design-time XAML. `AnchorablesSource` and `DocumentsSource` are two good examples that let us bind the layout to VM properties, instead of defining them in XAML at design-time.

Comment: @dotNET, "the layout" is actually "the view", so there is noting wrong to define this attribute in xaml or even do that in code-behind. In opposite, your view model must not manage any presentation aspects such as view layout.

Comment: @dymanoid: You have a valid point. That's what I ended up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later research revealed that it is actually the job of `LayoutInitializer` class to assign ViewModel objects to my `LayoutAnchorablePane`s. The layout itself should still be defined within XAML (or through code-behind if u wish). This is correct from theoretical point of view too; the ViewModel shouldn't be responsible for managing the layout (View).

Comment: Thank you for this hint!